# Log4Cxx as part of a static build

Tags: c++, log4cxx

Hi I'm doing some preliminary investigation into Log4Cxx and it seems as though it's a dynamic library. I'm wondering if it's possible to use it as part of a Static build.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The log4cxx package has a static library along with the dynamic library.  Use `-l:liblog4cxx.a` (note the full name) instead of the usual `-llog4cxx` when linking your program.